# Strange issue on Raspberry Pi UART (with FTDI USB <--> RS-232 adapter)

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, ftdi

I'm trying to establish a high speed UART communication on Raspberry Pi board. Since internal UART is not quite good at 1+ Mbaud, decided to use FTDI adapter (based on FT232RL chip) instead.

I've tested an adapter on my laptop running Debian 8 and reached stable transmission speed at 3 Mbaud (with a cat * >> /dev/ttyUSB0). 
Then plugged it to Pi2 doing exactly the same, and noticed this:

(at 3 Mbaud)
[image]

(at 1 Mbaud)
[image]

There are wide (up to 1 second at 3 Mbaud) gaps in transmission at regular time intervals. Transmitting data is not corrupted, just delayed. 
Any suggestion on how to overcome a problem? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps your data source is too slow,  try `cat /dev/zero >> /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: I've tried all kinds of data including UDP, TCP traffic over PPP. Gaps are staying the same.

Comment: What has UDD,TCP to do with UART? As your Rpi does also other things it can't send the data without gaps. Perhaps doing a custom kernel that uses all resources from RPi just to send data, the gaps would vanish, but what's the point of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

The problem was in RPi's USB driver.

[Answer](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=126010) from developer:

> At high baud rates, you may hit the USB NAK packet throttle threshold on outbound data - we have a crude mechanism implemented to stop FTDI devices from causing interrupt storms that lock the CPU out for extended periods of time. You can probably live with the increased interrupt rate on a Pi2 that comes from reducing the throttle interval.

After disabling NAK holdoff (by adding `dwc_otg.nak_holdoff=1` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`) it works perfect at 3 Mbaud.

Answer (score 1):

The RPi has only *one* USB Bus. One second long gaps sould be very rare, but you would see them if your *data source* for `cat *` uses the same USB bus to tranfer data *into* the RPi at the same time.

Something with more buffer like 
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ttyUSB0 bs=1M` should show less gaps, unless there are more USB devices active.

Comment: Does internal microSD card reader use the USB Bus? There are no USB devices connected to the board except the adapter.

Comment: I've tried to do output with your command - gaps are exactly the same.

Comment: The Ethernet port is on the USB 2.0 Bus. Do you see the gaps when ethernet is disconnected?

Comment: Yes. Ethernet is disconnected.